# Como puedo incluir Alertify a un boton que valida una consulta?

Tags: javascript, html

Me ayudarian a saber como poner una alerta  al presionar el boton de generar evento, los datos que necesito son mandados a otra pagina php que hace la consulta al momento de hacer la consulta necesito que valide si si se creo correctamente la consulta o se produjo algun error

```
<div class="container-longer">
                <div class="container" style="width:300px">
                     <form action="insertar.php" method="POST"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 txtEvento">
                                Evento:
                                <input name="txtEvento" placeholder="Nombre del Evento" style="width:270px" type="text">
                                </input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12 txtEvento">
                                Fecha y Hora:
                                <input name="txtFecha" placeholder="Fecha y Hora" style="width:270px" type="datetime-local">
                                </input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 textlogin">
                    <!-- Boton de Generar evento > -->
                        <input class="btn_login btn-primary me-md-2 btn" value= "Generar Evento"style="padding-left: 2.5rem; padding-right: 2.5rem;" type="submit" id="boton" src="imagenes/mas.png" type="image" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#boton").click(function(){  
        alertify.success('', 'Se ha creado :D!');
    });
```

Aca esta el codigo en el archivo php en el cual llevo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','itesa');
   $evento = $_POST['txtEvento'];
   $fecha = $_POST['txtFecha']; 
     $sqlTabla1 = "INSERT into eventos (Nombre_Evento, Fecha_Evento,Lugar_Evento,Id_Carrera) VALUES ('$evento','$fecha','$lugar','$carrera')";
   $ejecutado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlTabla1);
   if (!$ejecutado) {
    // Si la consulta falla, mostrar un mensaje de error con Alertify
    echo "<script>alertify.error('Error al agregar evento: ". mysqli_error($conexion) ."');</script>";
} else {
    // Si la consulta se ejecuta correctamente, redirigir a la página de eventos
    header("Location: http://localhost/Proyect/Generador%20de%20eventos.html");
} 
?>
```